# Validation failed: [attribute] can't be blank - (but it isn't!?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I have the following SupportSession model and validation rule:

```
class SupportSession < ApplicationRecord
  validates :cancelled, presence: true
```

But whenever I try and seed my database with the following data:

```
SupportSession.create!(venue: 'Cafe', mode_of_delivery: 'face-to-face', support_type: 'mentoring', start_time: '2019-05-15 16:12', end_time: '2019-05-15 16:35', total_breaks_mins: 0, duration_mins: 23, rounded_duration_mins: 30, status: 'ready', cancelled: false, support_allocation_id: 6)
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Cancelled can't be blank)
```

I'm confused because cancelled is clearly there in my seed data.

Here's the SupportSession table structure:

```
  t.string :venue
  t.string :mode_of_delivery
  t.string :support_type
  t.datetime :start_time
  t.datetime :end_time
  t.integer :duration_mins
  t.integer :rounded_duration_mins
  t.integer :total_breaks_mins
  t.string :status
  t.boolean :cancelled
  t.string :reason_for_cancellation
  t.datetime :rearranged_to
```

Any ideas?

I've also tried this in my model:

```
validates_presence_of
```

and used:

```
cancelled: '0'
cancelled: 0
cancelled: 'false'
```

But none seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`blank?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-blank-3F) returns true for a `false` value. The behavior of this method can be quite tricky when starting Rails. Just to name the most usual circumstances.

```
false.blank?     # => true
''.blank?        # => true
'   '.blank?     # => true
"\t\n\r".blank?  # => true
' blah '.blank?  # => false
```

You can get around this [by doing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank)

```
validates :cancelled, presence: true, allow_blank: true
```